# Compartilhar conexão VPN da máquina virtual com a máquina real

Tags: linux, windows, redes, virtualbox

estou com um problema pois comecei a utilizar a alguns meses `Ubuntu` e agora recentemente migrei para `Mint`.

Trabalho desevolvendo com `Java Web` mas para fazer testes preciso acessar a base de dados do cliente através de uma `VPN`. Infelizmente o instalador desta `VPN` somente existe para  `Windows` e `Mac`. Eu já tentei configurar conforme certos tutoriais mas não deram certo.

Então eu desenvolvo no ambiente Linux e certos testes e atividade eu executo na VM com Windows 7.

Queria saber se tem como eu compartilhar a conexão da `VM` quando ela fizer uso da `VPN` com a máquina `Linux` para configurar meu arquivo de `properties` apontando para o ip do banco de dados da empresa.

Porque quando vou no `prompt` e digito `ipconfig/all` ele mostra apenas o ip do banco.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado

Comment: Fiz uma máquina VM Windows usar uma conexão VPN estabelecida pela máquina Linux. Basicamente configurei uma rota na VM Windows dizendo que tudo que for para 192.168.10.0 deve ser redirecionado para o gateway para 10.10.0.18 (endereco do Linux na VPN). Posso postar a solução detalhada caso você queira.

Comment: Por favor, faça isso.

Comment: Note que é o contrário do que você precisa, mas talvez os passos que mostrarei te ajudem a configurar o que vc precisa. Ok?

Comment: @cantoni responde sim. Podes também perguntar no Meta se achares que pode ser off topic..

Answer (score 1):

Como dito nos comentários, o meu problema era diferente do relatado, pois, no meu caso, a conexão VPN está na máquina real (host) e eu preciso compartilhar com uma máquina virtual (guest).

Creio que, como dito, isso pode ajudar a fazer a configuração solicitada. O autor da pergunta concordou e pediu para eu respoder.

Meu ambiente é assim configuarado:

**Máquina Real (host)**

- Ubuntu 15.04
- OpenVpn
- Endereço na rede interna: 192.168.1.238
- Endereço na VPN: 10.20.0.50

O host conecta na VPN da empresa. A subrede das máquinas internas da VPN (ou seja, as máquinas da empresa) é 192.168.30.0

**Máquina Virtual (guest)**

- Windows 7
- Modo de configuração da rede: Bridge
- Endereço na rede interna: 192.168.1.216

**Objetivo**: fazer com que o Windows 7 (VM) tenha acesso à conexão VPN estabelecida pelo Ubuntu (host).

Uma opção é configurar a rede da VM para NAT (configuração padrão do VirtualBox). Isso faz a VPN funcionar no Windows, porém, isso não me resolve, já que eu preciso que essa máquina faça parte da rede interna da minha casa. Em outras palavras, preciso que ela tenha um endereço na rede 192.168.1.0 (rede interna da casa). Logo, ela precisa estar configurada como Bridge, não como NAT.

Assim, para resolver essa questão, adotei os seguintes passos:

1. **Configurar duas interfaces de rede na VM. A primeira em modo Bridge, a segunda em modo NAT.**

Essa configuração no VirtualBox fará com que o Windows tenha duas interfaces de rede, uma na rede 192.168.1.0 (casa) e outra na rede 10.0.3.0 (rede do próprio VirtualBox, não confundir com a rede da VPN). Para dúvidas, ver modo NAT do VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes

**Importante**: O fato de estar na rede 10.0.3.0 é o que permite acesso à rede do Host e é por causa disso que posso pingar, a partir da VM, o endereço do host na VPN (10.20.0.50).

2. **Criar um roteamento entre a VM e o endereço da VPN.**

Como dito acima, é possível acessar o 10.20.0.50 a partir da VM. Dessa maneira, para finalizar, bastou criar uma rota no Windows. Siga os passos:

- Abrir o prompt do Windows como Administrador;
- Digitar a seguinte linha: **route -p add 192.168.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.20.0.50**
- Pronto. A máquina Windows agora pode acessar a VPN.

**Explicação**: o comando cima adiciona uma linha na tabela de roteamento do Windows especificando que qualquer acesso a endereços da rede 192.168.30.0 devem ser roteados para o 10.20.0.50. O parametro -p indica que essa rota deve ser persistente, assim, quando a máquina for reiniciada a rota será configurada automaticamente.

**O cenário da pergunta**

O autor tem a necessidade inversa, ou seja, a conexão VPN está na VM e ele precisa que o host tenha acessa a ela. A primeira coisa a se verificar é se, a partir do host, consegue-se pingar o IP da VPN no guest. Caso consiga, então você pode definir um roteamento no Linux (host), dizendo que conexões para os endereçoes da sub-rede da empresa sejam roteadas para esse endereço da VPN na VM. Enfim, é o contrário do exposto aqui, mas os conceitos são exatamente os mesmos, já que se trata de roteamento (camada 3).